# How to use same fragment for multiple activity?

Tags: inheritance, android-activity

I am writing an application with multiple activity. I wrote an fragment which have some common logic that can be use by multiple activity for different flow.

I can use it simply to launch fragment from Activity using:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit();
```

Basis on parent activity, fragment also have some if-else case to handle.
So how can get Activity object inside:

One way I know using **onAttach** but how to define which Activity-obj is this.

Any suggestion here !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been solved, it's simple Java inheritance. I used interface that is extended by both activity and in reference it cast based on Interface instead of Direct class name.

Comment: Hi,Me also faced same problem.if u don't mind please provide some sample to me.thanq

Comment: Get an interface say CommonInterface with method decollation you need. Now both of your activity has implementation of same interface. Now check Fragment.onAttach get instance of Activity and check for isInstance of Activity A/B. let me know if it helped you.